# calculate data binding for a repeat control

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have 2 domino views bound to an xpage. view1 and view2.
In a repeat control I would like to calculate to which view I want to bind the repeat control.

In the repeat control, data, value , you have for example # view1 ,(as data source) if you don't calculate anything.
When I use ssjs and I return view1 , it's not working.(the repeat control doesn't bind  to view1)

What do I have to return in ssjs to bind the repeat control to view1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the "view1" variable from a view data source is a little unusual, in that the binding to a repeat/view/etc. deals with the data source as it is, while the value in an SSJS context is the lotus.domino.View object itself, which is different.

In any event, though you CAN compute the repeat's binding on page load (by using page-load-sexecuted SSJS to return a value binding string, e.g. `value="${javascript:'#{' + (someCondition ? 'view1' : 'view2') + '}'}"`), you'd probably be better off computing the viewName property of the view data source instead. That should behave a bit more like you'd expect.

Comment: I agree with the approach of calculating the view name property of the view data source.

Comment: Not only the view is different , but the search in the view is different also.Of course I could have calculated that too. I was also thinking of using the dynamic content control.